# Readability mobilizer in commercial a iOS app

Tags: ios, rss, html-parsing, readability

So as the title says, does anyone know, if I can use Readability's mobilizer in a paid app?

I mean like using this: 
http://www.readability.com/m?url=http://www.cnn.com/2013/01/11/showbiz/tv/golden-globes-tv-vineyard/index.html?hpt=hp_abar
in an app that's not going to be free?

I googled, searched Readability's web and blog, but found nothing about mobilizer, only reader, parser and shortener apis.

Thanks for any response,

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

From their [developer documentation](https://www.readability.com/developers/api/parser):

> The Parser API is freely available on a limited basis. If you'd like to use the Parser API for commercial use, get in touch with us at licensing@readability.com to learn about our licensing options.

I'd say that if your usage of Readability is key to your app, you probably would need to pay. But just get in touch with them.